# java.lang.NullPointerException when deserializing

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, deserialization

```
public class ViewBooking extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ViewBooking
     */
    public ViewBooking() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void dispBookingInfo(){
        Reservation[] reservations = new Reservation[1];

        try {
            String searchCust = SearchName.getText();
            FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(searchCust +
                    "booking.dat");
            ObjectInputStream objectInputFile = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);

            reservations[0] = (Reservation) objectInputFile.readObject();
            objectInputFile.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, reservations[0].getDetails());
    }
```

This is my Reservation class

```
public class Reservation implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String sDate;
    private String eDate;
    private String noOfDays;
    private String roomNo;
    private String totalAmt;

    Reservation(String name, String sDate, String eDate, String noOfDays,
            String totalAmt, String roomNo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.totalAmt = totalAmt;
        this.roomNo = roomNo;
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getsDate() {
        return sDate;
    }

    public void setsDate(String sDate) {
        this.sDate = sDate;
    }

    public String geteDate() {
        return eDate;
    }

    public void seteDate(String eDate) {
        this.eDate = eDate;
    }

    public String getNoOfDays() {
        return noOfDays;
    }

    public void setNoOfDays(String noOfDays) {
        this.noOfDays = noOfDays;
    }

    public String getRoomNo() {
        return roomNo;
    }

    public void setRoomNo(String roomNo) {
        this.roomNo = roomNo;
    }

    public String getTotalAmt() {
        return totalAmt;
    }

    public void setTotalAmt(String totalAmt) {
        this.totalAmt = totalAmt;
    }

    public String getDetails(){
        return "Name: " + name + "\n" + "From: " + sDate + " to " + eDate
            + "\n" + "Duration: " + noOfDays + "Room No: " + roomNo
            + "Total amount: RM" + totalAmt;
    }
}
```

I am able to serialize the Reservation object but when i try to deserialize it and read the data, i get a `NullPointerException` error at this line:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, reservations[0].getDetails());
```

What is the problem here?

I have changed my code into the following:

```
public void dispBookingInfo() throws Exception{
    String searchCust = SearchName.getText();
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(searchCust + " booking.dat");
    ObjectInputStream objectInputFile = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
    Reservation[] reservations = new Reservation[1];

    try {


        if (reservations[0] != null) {
          reservations[0] = (Reservation) objectInputFile.readObject();  
        }

        objectInputFile.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error!");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, reservations[0].getDetails());
}
```

The NullPointerException error is gone but I still cant retrieve any data. Why is my `reservation[0]` null?

Comment: You're catching `Exception` and then doing nothing with it. This is probably hiding your true problem from you. Think about it: `reservations[0]` must be `null` for that exception to pop out, so what did your catch swallow up? Have you also verified that the file you're reading from exists *and contains data*?

Comment: Post your stack trace and don't swallow exceptions like this "catch (Exception e) {}"

Comment: @JonK the file that I'm reading from does exist and contains data. Why is the: `reservations[0]` null?

Comment: The best any of us can do to answer that is guess. You need to output some meaningful message in your `catch` block so that you can find out what's really going wrong inside your `try`. Even something as simple as `e.printStackTrace();` would give you a point in the right direction.

Comment: `"error!"` isn't a meaningful message to output - it doesn't tell you anything about the error, just that one occurred. Print the stack trace instead.

Comment: I've printed the stack trace and I still get the NullpointerException error

Comment: There should now be two stack traces, what does the first one show?

Comment: I replaced the array objects with normal objects and it works now. But there are still some info missing. I will try to work that out

Answer (score 3):

In your

```
try {
    ...
} catch () {
    ...
}
```

statement you ignore any exception thrown. Hence it is possible that

```
reservations[0] = (Reservation) objectInputFile.readObject();
```

does not initialize `reservation[0]` at all, which would cause an `NullPointerException` when accessing:

```
reservation[0].getDetails();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
if (reservations[0] != null) {
    reservations[0] = (Reservation) objectInputFile.readObject();  
}
```

`reservations[0]` will *always* be `null` at this point because you've only just initialised the array. This stops the call that would populate the data into here, so when you try and access it later on with `reservations[0].getDetails()` that element is inevitably still `null`. The `null` check is completely unneeded, so remove it.

You may also wish to consider defining a `serialVersionUID` for your class.

To do so, add this as a class variable:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = <some_long_number>;
```

Replace `<some_long_number>` with any `long` that you like. Once done, you'll have to re-create your file with a 'new' version of your class, otherwise the version numbers won't match.

If you don't do this, the JVM automatically generates a `serialVersionUID` for you based upon the class itself, so if you've changed certain things about the class, you may suddenly find that you have problems deserialising older versions of the class.